# Trigger Apache Storm Window

Tags: apache-storm

I have been working on a stream processing project that streaming on incoming data using the sliding window technique on Apache Storm (v1.1.0).

I tried to portray the problem which I have in the picture below. Let me explain. e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6,e7,e8 are my events and coming to Apache Storm in time order. w1,w2,w3 etc represent the window name.

- Between[0,5] there are events
- Between[5,10] there are events
- Between[10,15] there are not events
- Between[15,20] there are not events
- Between[20,25] there are not events
- Between[25,30] there is event
- Between[30,25] there is event

As an output, Apache Storm creates **w1, w2, w3, w6** windows, but does not create **w4** and **w5**

The problem is I need **w4** and **w5** for my logic. What can I do for that. I want to receive window even if there is no event for window

[image: Sliding Window Example]

Comment: You will need to give more information on your implementation for someone to help you with this. Is this windowing happening in a spout or bolt? Can you show your `nextTuple()` or `execute()` method code so we can see if there any conditional statements that might not be triggered.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing we're talking about the windowing support described [here](https://storm.apache.org/releases/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/Windowing.html)?

I would try enabling [tick tuples](https://kitmenke.com/blog/2014/08/04/tick-tuples-within-storm/) for your bolt. It should make Storm send a tuple to your bolt with some interval, which should allow you to avoid empty windows.